# FOSUserBundle in Symfony2.5: how to erase the data table User with an existing

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I use the *FOSUserBundle* on my Symfony2.5 project. I work on an **existing database**.

The problem is that a `user` table already exists. When generating database with *Doctrine* and *FOSUserBundle* , I have a **duplication** (ie two tables : User by FOSUserbundle and user by the existing database). How do I to tell *FOSUserbundle* / *Doctrine* the table is that existing or erase the existing one?

I would also like to change some field in the User (of FOSUser) table or delete some generated , how do I do this?

I noticed that FOSUser uses a management right , but I also have a table `rights` in my existing database . I take it off and I manage **user right** with *FOSUser* or I keep the table?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I just delete the user table wich already exist in the database project, and I add the relation following the cookbook of [Symfony](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)